# JSON could not be parsed error in Python

Tags: python, json, http, post

I'm trying to write a Python script to make an Amazon purchase using the Zinc API (see: https://zinc.io/docs/#full-api). I should be able to do this through a single POST request, so I read up about urllib and urllib2 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data).

However, when I run my script, I receive this error:

```
{"_type":"error","code":"invalid_json","message":"The JSON in your request could not be parsed."}
```

I'm following Zinc's code pretty precisely, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Here is what I'm running (Note: my personal information is excluded, but included when I run the script):

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://api.zinc.io/v0/order'
values = {"client_token" : "public",
          "retailer" : "amazon",
          "products" :[{"product_id" : "0679753354", "quantity" : 1}],
          "max_price" : 1700, "shipping_address" : {
              "first_name" : "NAME",
              "last_name" : "NAME",
              "address_line1" : "ADDRESS",
              "address_line2" : "",
              "zip_code" : "ZIP",
              "city" : "CITY",
              "state" : "STATE",
              "country" : "US"
              },
          "is_gift" : False,
          "shipping_method" : "cheapest",
          "payment_method" : {
              "name_on_card" : "NAME",
              "number" : "CARDNUMBER",
              "security_code" : "SECCODE",
              "expiration_month" : 1,
              "expiration_year": 2015
              },
          "billing_address" : {
              "first_name" : "NAME",
              "last_name" : "NAME",
              "address_line1" : "ADDRESS",
              "address_line2" : "",
              "zip_code" : "ZIP",
              "city" : "CITY",
              "state" : "STATE",
              "country" : "US",
              "phone_number" : "PHONE"
              },
          "retailer_credentials" : {
              "email" : "EMAIL",
              "password" : "PASSWORD"}
          }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

Any ideas on how to fix this JSON parsing issue would be much appreciated, as I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Hi fnwtp, i hope you are doing well. I am trying to build an application using the ZINC api, I was curious how is it working for you so far? CYou mentioned that "I am following Zinc's code pretty precisely," from where? Could you please tell me the steps I need to follow I am not familiar with python. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to urlencode that data. That's for form values, not JSON.

In addition, you've imported the `json` module, but you're not using it on your data. You should do it like this:

```
data = json.dumps(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Although it's much easier and better to use the third-party [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This works perfectly. I'll definitely check out the requests library. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You're url encoding your request, but not turning the Python data into JSON that the server can understand. Instead of calling urllib.urlencode(values), you should call json.dumps(values).

For example:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://api.zinc.io/v0/order'
values = {"client_token" : "public",
          "retailer" : "amazon",
          "products" :[{"product_id" : "0679753354", "quantity" : 1}],
          "max_price" : 1700, "shipping_address" : {
              "first_name" : "NAME",
              "last_name" : "NAME",
              "address_line1" : "ADDRESS",
              "address_line2" : "",
              "zip_code" : "ZIP",
              "city" : "CITY",
              "state" : "STATE",
              "country" : "US"
              },
          "is_gift" : False,
          "shipping_method" : "cheapest",
          "payment_method" : {
              "name_on_card" : "NAME",
              "number" : "CARDNUMBER",
              "security_code" : "SECCODE",
              "expiration_month" : 1,
              "expiration_year": 2015
              },
          "billing_address" : {
              "first_name" : "NAME",
              "last_name" : "NAME",
              "address_line1" : "ADDRESS",
              "address_line2" : "",
              "zip_code" : "ZIP",
              "city" : "CITY",
              "state" : "STATE",
              "country" : "US",
              "phone_number" : "PHONE"
              },
          "retailer_credentials" : {
              "email" : "EMAIL",
              "password" : "PASSWORD"}
          }

req = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(values))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```